# абстрактные классы и интерфейсы на конкретном примере

Tags: java, ооп

После изучения многих статей про абстрактные классы и интерфейсы, в целом все понятно зачем они и чем отличаются, и примеры с кошками и собаками, а так же с дверями и домами это все мило и понятно, но вот в один момент ты переходишь к практике, и тут конкретно у меня возник вопрос - "WT*?" А точнее я не очень понимаю как грамотно спроектировать мне приложение. Вот я хочу написать чисто для себя домашнюю бухгалтерию, хватит пользоваться Екселем, яж программист)))
Как говорится в тех же статьях сначала надо написать абстрактные классы, или интерфейсы, но в голове у меня крутятся кошки и собаки и я не пойму как мне это сделать на моем примере. Я знаю что я хочу сделать в итоге и как оно должно выглядить, но как мне построить интерфейсы? Я работаю с базой данных, то есть я так понимаю, мне можно написать в интерфейсе методы подключения к БЗ, и метод вызова SQL запроса например для обязательной реализации. Я понимаю, что наверное в данном (небольшом) проекте использовать данную структуру нет необходимости, но просто хочется больше практике, и в принципе что я прошу, помогите мне пожалуйста понять, как правильно все же использовать интерфейсы и абстрактные классы, желательно на данном примере, допустим Вы пишите бухгалтерию, бизнес-логика у Вас есть, реализуете регистрацию и авторизацию через БД, данные все храните как локально, так и на сервере.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Используйте пока что-то одно. В Вашей задаче - интерфейс. Понимание прийдет с практикой

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi а как бы вы прописали в данной ситуации интерфейс?

Comment: Сконцентрируйтесь на одном, конкретном вопросе. Сейчас Вы хотите чтобы Вам объяснили для чего нужно (1) ооп, (2) наследование, (3) интерфейсы, (4) абстракные классы, (5) все это на примере с бухгалтерией, (6) с подключением к БД, (7) с бизнес логикой, (8) с регистрацией, (8) с авторизацией, (9) с хранением данных локально, (10) на сервере. По каждой из этих тем пишутся толстенные книги с десятками вариантов реализации, для одного вопроса тем как-то многовато.

Comment: @defaultlocale может я не внятно объяснился, но по факту меня интересую только (3) и (4) пункт, да на конкретном примере, например как в ответе от Anton

Comment: @VladZherihov боюсь, что не очень внятно, может попробуете поправить вопрос, выделить в нем главное и убрать лишнее? Сейчас в вопросе много всего и после прочтения неясно что именно должно быть в ответе.

Comment: Вы хотите создать БД и пользоваться ею. У Вас будут какие-то сущности, которые должны поддерживать `CRUD` операции (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE). Вот их и прописывайте, а в соответствующих классах реализуйте. Погуглите **DAO hibernate implementation**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. Использовать нормальную структуру необходимо всегда. Ведь никогда не знаешь, к чему приведет в конечном итоге твоя работа. Теперь к вопросу "что делать?". Смотри, у тебя есть примерное представляение, как должна работать программа. Разбиваешь её на части (назовем их слои (Layers)).
К примеру, (в достаточно простом варианте) слои могут быть

1. Визуализация данных
2. Логика (составление отчетов, рассчет налогов итд)
3. Сервисы работы с БД.

Каждый слой должен взаимодействовать с другими слоями лишь с помощью абстрактных классов и интерфейсов. Так же поступаем с любыми моментами, в которых есть возможность неодназначного поведения.

А дальше все совсем просто. Начинаешь писать логику одного слоя, а когда требуется взаимодействие с другим слоем - пишешь для этого интерфейс (на этом этапе еще рано про абстрактные классы думать). Затем переходишь на следующий слой, имплементишь интерфейсы и пишешь логику нового слоя... И так до того момента, пока программа не будет написана

P.s. я пропустил моменты логирования и тестирования как сами собой разумеющиеся.

Answer (score 2):

Попробую предложить тебе свое понимание интерфейсов и абстрактных классов.

Программирование не любит самоповторов, поэтому если ты видишь, что у тебя несколько классов реализуют одинаковый функционал, то лучше всего его вынести в абстрактный класс. Например, у тебя есть 3 вида отчета, недельный месячный годовой или для себя, для жены, для инвестора. В каждом этом случае эти классы будут предельно похожи друг на друга, но чем-то все-же чуть-чуть отличаться... вот это отличие ты оставляешь, а их делаешь наследниками одного абстрактного класса, в который уже и заносишь всю их похожесть.

Теперь про интерфейсы. Какими бы разными отчеты о твоей бухгалтерии не были.... 
метод работы с ними (вероятно) совершенно одинаковы... показать на экране, распечатать на принтере, сохранить... и т.п. При этом Java строго-типизированный  язык и если метод принимает в параметры скажем ReportForMine то ReportForWife он уже не примет. И как быть, писать кучу повторяющихся методов отличающихся лишь принимаемым типом? Теперь смотри, как удобно будет решить через интерфейс.

Пусть все разные виды отчетов реализуют один и тот же интерфейс (Report) соответственно метод, скажем public void save(Report report) сможет принять все эти разные отчеты и сохранить их. Удобно!

Comment: спасибо, буду реализовывать